# Изменение ширины блока (в обе стороны) при скролле страицы

Tags: javascript, css, анимация

Есть код, который управляет шириной элемента `<div class="ani">`. Задача была такая: при скроллинге страницы иногда встречается `<div class="ani">` (встречается несколько раз на странице). Сейчас у меня 2 проблемы:

1. Меняется ширина элемента сразу же как только пользователь начинает скроллить в самом верху страницы, а нужно, что бы ширина менялась когда доскроллишь до самого `<div class="ani">`.
2. Если на странице 2 и более `<div class="ani">`, то работает только первый, остальные, те что ниже первого, не работают

Ниже приведу сам код:

```js
<script>
let h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
let div = document.querySelector(".ani");
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

  if (pageYOffset > (h / 0.001)) {
   div.style.width = '100%'

  } else {
   div.style.width = pageYOffset + 'px';
  
  }
  
});
</script>
```

```css
.ani {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -13px;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  min-width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #FF5714;
  width: 1%;
  height: 2px;
  transition: width 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="ani"></div>
```

Comment: перебрать надо в цикле ...for или forEach эти блоки

Answer (score -2):

В переменную div вы и забираете только первый элемент DOM. (поэтому и работает только с первым элементом)
В строке pageYOffset > (h / 0.001) - что-то не то совсем написано. Вы берете всю высоту элемента, а потом на кой-то черт делите, например 300рх на 0.001 (Почему тогда не на 0.000000001 ?) зачем это ? Вы же понимаете, что событие скролл ПОСТОЯННО будет заниматься этим неподобством с делением ? *Я уже молчу что размеры h по хорошему могут меняться в процессе ресайза окна браузера, а вы эту переменную харткодите, без фидбека

Comment: Может подскажете какой то другой скрипт?